# Install osgeo live package in existing Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, osgeo, osgeo-live

I am using Ubuntu. In my secondary computer I use Lubuntu based OSGEO-LIVE 12.0. OSGEO-LIVE is a great software when it comes to any GIS application and reduces tedious work of individual package installation. But I want to set up all the packages from OSGEO-live into my existing Ubuntu 18.4.

Is there any way of doing this in bulk in short time?

Answer (score 4):

I have also Ubuntu 18.04 and I use OSGeoLive in a virtual machine.
I've installed VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

After it I downloaded the *osgeolive-12.0-vm.7z* from https://sourceforge.net/projects/osgeo-live/files/12.0/

You should install 7z

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Unzip the downloaded file

```
7z -x osgeolive-12.0-vm.7z
```

Create a new virtual machine in virtualbox (GUI) and use it.

You can find more information here: https://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/virtualization_quickstart.html.

Note: there should be enough memory in your machine to run both OS at the same time (8 GB in my case is enough).

Comment: I would prefer using all those packages in my existing os i.e ubuntu 18.04. so is there any repository or something so that i can get all those packages installed in my current machine???

Comment: Which package cannot you install using apt?

Comment: UbuntuGIS repo may help but the stabile repo contains too old packages (e.g. QGIS 2.14).

Answer (score 1):

Check the OSGeoLive team launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/~osgeolive

You can access all the packages for OSGLive 13 adding the repository to apt:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:osgeolive/release-13.0`

> Is there any way of doing this in bulk in short time?

There are 111 packages there. You can install all of them in one line if you want :-)